# Java - I need a very fast image scaling algorithm

Tags: java, image-processing, image-manipulation, midp, image-scaling

I am working on a Midlet application. I am finding myself in the need to scale images very often. This has become a problem because some phones are pretty slow and scaling takes too long.

Currently I'm using Image.createRGBImage(int, int, int, boolean) to scale the image.

I was wondering if any of you knew of a very efficient and fast way to scale an image.

**Note:** this is a Midlet application so only JavaME is available, meaning I don't have access to some other libraries available in the full java version.

**Note2:** most of my scaling is done from small to large images, although I also do scale down the image.

Comment: what sizes are you talking about? is the % change arbitrary or some simple multiple (like 2x)?

Comment: one way to optimize is to use mipmapping: http://www.3drender.com/glossary/mipmapping.htm

Comment: The scale size is arbitrary. Let's say my image is 100px by 65px. I need to scale it to any size I want. Let's say 200px by 500px, or 1200px by 10px. So it needs to be scaled up or down either vertically or horizontally, and/or any combination of both.

Comment: @Tony What libraries can you use, or does this have to be home grown?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Keep in mind that **there's always a trade between speed and image quality** when discussing scaling algorithms, and the ideal solution for your case might require some research and testing.

**[Nearest neighbor](http://tech-algorithm.com/articles/nearest-neighbor-image-scaling/)** is the **simplest and fastest** implementation of image scaling.

There's a nice intro on image scale/resize on [Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/07/better-image-resizing.html) which reviews a couple of  techniques and compares their quality.

I imagine you are working with a very small displaying device, so image quality doesn't really matter at the end. Some people are calling [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20170809062128/http://willperone.net/Code/codescaling.php) **the fastest** image scaling implementation for **J2ME**.

But if you are willing to read some other stuff, [this paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20150218020203/https://www.compuphase.com/graphic/scale.htm) presents a low cost (meaning "very fast") algorithm for scaling that significantly improves on nearest neighbor interpolation. There's source code available, and they also present an evolution of that research [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109193008/http://www.compuphase.com:80/graphic/scale2.htm).

At last but not least, [`cvResize()`](http://opencv.jp/opencv-2svn_org/py/imgproc_geometric_image_transformations.html#resize) from OpenCV (open source/cross-platform library for image processing). The folks at *willow garage* are pretty good at making fast procedures for image/video processing, and this function provides a couple of techniques for scaling, so it might be worth to check it's implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently using the technique you describe in your link: "Some people are calling this the fastest image scaling implementation for J2ME."

I will review the other techniques and do some testing and see if I get any faster scaling. Thumbs up for your excellent answer. Points go to you. Thanks Karl.